# Vagrant The machine is in the 'gurumeditation' state After Installing Android Emulator and Minikube

Tags: android-studio, kubernetes, vagrant, virtualbox, kvm

Hy folks, I'm using Vagrant box provisioned with Ansible and provider Oracle virtualbox, it was working fine for me. 
But one day i installed Android Studio and it's Emulator and Minicube wit KVM.

Afterwards vagrant with virtual-box just stop working. Now whenever i run `vagrant up` i get below error.

```sh
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/bionic64' version '20200416.0.0' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'gurumeditation' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

**I need to run all of three on Ubuntu, How can i fix this?**

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/420663/268809 are you starting in the correct order?

Answer (score 2):

1) Stop the VM

```
VBoxManage  controlvm  vm_123 poweroff
```

2) The check the settings.
VirtualBox will likely tell you there are some incompatible settings; correct those.

It could be the embedded virtualisation, or 32 vs 64 bits, or the amount of RAM for display or the virtual VGA display type, etc.

Comment: You can get the vm name by running: VBoxManage list vms

Answer (score 1):

I had a gurumeditation issue with a fresh debian/buster64 and a reboot of my laptop fixed it (Virtualbox was only tellig me that the state was invalid in the log).

Some time lost for nothing. If ever it can help